# How can I display the values excluded by the Where clause?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, inner-join, where-clause

I'm trying to figure out how to to display all those values that are excluded from this WHERE clause instead of those that are chosen by:

```
    $pdo = $service->pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT a.id, a.name, a.surname, a.job, b.start_date, b.end_date
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b on b.id = a.id
    WHERE a.job = '{$job}'
    AND
    STR_TO_DATE(b.`start_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') = '{$date}'
    GROUP BY a.id ";
    return $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

What this query returns are values that match "work title" first and then values that exist in that date in the table 2. What I'm trying to show are all the other values based on the "work title" excluding those values that exist for that specific date. Basically I need to figure out for example how to know who is free in a specific date based on this query.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Pls provide sample data, expected results and the results returned by your attempt. This will help us to understand your problem better and we can come up with a verifiable solution.

Comment: Yes of course. What does it return is an array of workers based on the job title. I.E: Asking for Form 1: Backliner - Form 2: 07-06-2018 . With that query what I m expecting is who is working on 07-06-2018 that is a backliner. But in table 1 there are more backliner then who is working. What I need is to show results from table1 that are not in the table2 in that date.

Comment: This is not what I asked for.

Comment: What kind of sample data you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query and set the inverse where clause like this, you get the rows that don't match 'work title' OR (this is important) the rows that don't match the date requeriment in table2:

```
    $pdo = $service->pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT a.id, a.name, a.surname, a.job, b.start_date, b.end_date
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b on b.id = a.id
    WHERE a.job <> '{$job}'
    OR
    STR_TO_DATE(b.`start_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') <> '{$date}'
    GROUP BY a.id ";
    return $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

**EDIT**

After reading your comments, i see that you don´t need the roes that your query has dircarded, you need the rows that match the first requeriment and don't match the second one. So you would need it this way:

```
    $pdo = $service->pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT a.id, a.name, a.surname, a.job, b.start_date, b.end_date
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b on b.id = a.id
    WHERE a.job = '{$job}'
    AND
    STR_TO_DATE(b.`start_date`, '%d-%m-%Y') <> '{$date}'
    GROUP BY a.id ";
    return $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Ok cool but in the table2 there are other rows that satisfies the condition so what it returns is to ignore rows with that date but it shows all the workers with that title job because they exist in other date. What I'm trying to do is to display in a table only values that basically doesn't exist in the table2 but only in that specific date. I need to show people from table1 that not exist in table2 only in the required date.

Comment: Is like to show certain values from table1 (job_title, name, surname etc) that are not in the table2 but only for one specific date that is required